# Paralleling op-amps for more current?

Tags: current-source

I'm trying to design a current source / sink that will be a part of a step generator that will drive a BJT base. I only intend to drive small BJT transistors so a max base current of 10mA was decided upon (somewhat arbitrary).

The circuit I'm using is the following one:
[image: current source]

The circuit can be re-configured by changing the polarity of the current source to sink. Using an op-amp with ultra-high input impedance / low input bias this circuit can go to nano amps and I intend to try and get close to that.

The op-amp of choice is TI (BB) OPA128 which has a typical current out rating of +/- 10mA. This seems about right, but I am a little worried that I will be stressing the device.

I have a couple of these devices, can I simply connect two of them in parallel or some other configuration so they will be able to drive a constant current of 10mA without too much "effort"?

Comment: Given the 10ma is arbitary and limited by your choice of opamp, why not choose a different opamp? Or a transistor with a bigger beta? What's the transistor driving?

Comment: @pjc50 I could not find an op-amp with more suitable input characteristics really. The transistor will be the "device under test" in a curve tracer of sorts.

Comment: If you're within its ratings you're within its ratings. Why make the design more complicated? (I'd be more worried at 10A, but at 10mA I'd be surprised if you could damage the opamp this way)

Comment: +/- 10 ma is the typical maximum output but it could be as low as +/- 5.  Why not drive an N-channel MOSFET gate with the op amp output?  You could use the voltage in the source-to-ground resistor as your current sense.  Put a resistor between the drain and the base of your BJT so that the gate voltage is in the middle of your power supply.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead Can you please include a schematic?

Comment: Related, possibly a dupe: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/188938/51760. My answer discusses the parallel combination of op amps for more current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try an output buffer something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJjIVl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As well as not exceeding the op-amp output capability you probably want to minimize the self-heating to improve the accuracy. The degradation with increasing die temperature is profound, and there's no sense throwing away performance of a stupidly expensive component (of course maybe you don't need to worry about low bias current **and** high current simultaneously in this application).

[image]

---

Edit: Below is a simulation you can play with. It's 100mA. You have to keep the output from saturating- so depending on op-amp and current the output might be able get within a few volts or less of each supply bus. The op-amp is supplying 1.4mA to get 200mA of load current (the output carries both the input and output current).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fybdna.png)</sup>

Comment: What is R1 for? In addition, I understand what you say about the offset current degradation, however I can live with 1pA as the lowest I'm shooting for is in the nA range. Won't the transistors suffer from the same problem with even larger variations eventually hurting the output accuracy? Thanks!

Comment: I think R1 will improve the stability near zero output current - otherwise it has to slew 2 Vbe near 0. The transistors don't enter into the accuracy nor does their leakage (or temperature)  matter much- and they won't heat the sensitive front end.

Comment: I've simulated the circuit and when the original circuit sinks 100uA (both resistors = 10k), the transistors junction is sourcing 4.436mA with a load of 1k resistor.

Comment: Above is a simulation with 100mA, the op-amp current is only 1.4mA. Of course you have to keep the output from saturating.

Comment: So instead of a stable current source, I'll need a bipolar voltage source like a DAC or something, correct?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish so it's hard to answer that. If you don't change R2 in your circuit you'll run into offset and noise at low currents. Bipolar output requires bipolar current input, of course. You can mirror currents off rails pretty easily using op-amps and transistors.

Comment: I'm referring to V3. In the circuit I have posted seems to me like a slight variation on the Howland current pump. How do you call the topology you suggested?

Comment: Oh, V3 is just a random voltage I picked to simulate the voltage drop across the load. Your circuit is the same topology as mine- I just added a complementary emitter follower buffer on the op-amp. It's still your circuit. I don't know if it has a name.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

See the picture.  The source and drain current are the same.  I hope this helps.